# Execute multiple runners for single gitlab CI pipeline

Tags: gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ci.yml

I have a gitlab CI configured to build and deploy code to 3 different servers with just minor changes before deploying each. Before deploying, I edit some files based on the server they are being deployed and push to the same repo from the CI pipeline.
For this purpose, I want to use 3 different runners to run in order to build and deploy the code to each server but couldn't find how to do it.
I can make each job in pipeline to run in parallel (using parallel matrix) on multiple runners, but the order in which the jobs run (i.e. execute 1 job first on all runners), the changes will not persist till the deploy job.

Is there a way I can trigger multiple runners to execute same job? or is their a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Define unique [tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/#tags) for each of your runners (ex. `deploy-win11`, `deploy-rhel8`, `deploy-solaris`).

Create a [template job](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends) and three jobs (each for one target system) that extends the template job. Then define [required tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#tags) for each of these three jobs.

Enjoy success, where each job runs on its own specific runner, deploying the correct version of your software.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand the question, but I think you're missing `stages`.

You can define your stages like this in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`
(you can name them however you want):

```
stages:
- build
- test
- deploy
```

This way, the pipeline will wait until all `build` jobs finish before it will run the `test` jobs.

Now, you have to specify in which stage a job should execute:

```
build_job_1:
  variables:
    NODE_OPTIONS: --max_old_space_size=8192
    GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS: none
  stage: build
  tags:
    - runner1

build_job_2:
  variables:
    NODE_OPTIONS: --max_old_space_size=4096
  stage: build
  tags:
    - runner2
```